# Google Api Keys for Windows Phone App

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, google-custom-search

I want to integrate google custom search in windows phone app for image searching
I create the project on https://console.developers.google.com/

When i went to API & Authentication section of project description to create Api key,A popup is giving only four option server key,browser key,android key and ios key.There is no option to create api key for windows phone app.

Is it not possible to integrate google custom search in windows phone app.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Feel free to opt for iOS key, it does not matter. I did so previously while working with Google Tasks API and all is fine...

Comment: how did you secure it?

Answer (score 2):

I created a browser key for my applications and also added URL wildcards for sites I would like the CSE to search such as

*.com; *.org; *.net etc.

Hope that helps!