# Google Places API | Can I use Android key in my WindowsPhone application

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, google-places-api

I have android application that use `Google Places API`
(I generated a key for my android application to be able use `Google Places API` with bigger quota then without this key).

Now I'm porting this app to Windows Phone 8.0 OS

1. Does it legitimate to use the same key in my Windows Phone app?
2. Can [OAuth .NET Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) helps me to get this key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about using API Keys but if you follow this [sample](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#wp) by Google, you can create an App for Windows 8.0 by using `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker`.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324921/google-api-keys-for-windows-phone-app) does talk about using iOS/Browser keys to be used for such a purpose but I would suggest against following such a process.